# How can i insert properly values from postman to my Node API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to Node and i've been trying to create an API and test it in postman but after sending values from postman i'm receiving this error

```
     password:
      { ValidatorError: Path `password` is required.
          at new ValidatorError (D:\devconnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validator.js:29:11)
          at validate (D:\devconnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:978:13)
          at D:\devconnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1031:11
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
          at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (D:\devconnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:987:14)
          at D:\devconnector\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2101:9
          at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:9)
        message: 'Path `password` is required.',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'required',
        path: 'password',
        value: undefined,
        reason: undefined,
        [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true } },
  _message: 'users validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

below is my server.js script

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const users = require('./routes/api/users');
const profile = require('./routes/api/profile');
const posts = require('./routes/api/posts');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
//Body Parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;
//Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(db).then(()=> console.log('MongoDB Connected')).catch(err => console.log(err));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>res.send('Hello World'));
//use routes
app.use('/api/users',users);
app.use('/api/profile',profile);
app.use('/api/posts',posts);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, ()=> console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Here is my key.js script

```
module.exports={
    //mongoURI:'mongodb://root:qwerty123@devconnector-u2cub.mongodb.net:27017'
    mongoURI:'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/devconnector'
};
```

The users.js script

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const gravatar = require('gravatar');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
// Load User model
const User = require('../../models/User');
//@route GET api/users/test
//@desc Tests post route
//@ access public
router.get('/test',(req, res) => res.json({msg: "Users Works2"}));
//@route GET api/users/register
//@desc Register user
//@ access public
router.post('/register',(req, res)=>{
    User.findOne({email:req.body.email})
    .then(user=>{
        if(user){
            return res.status(400).json({email: 'Email already exists'});
        }else{
            const avatar = gravatar.url(req.body.email,{
                s:'200',//size
                r: 'pg',//rating
                d: 'mm' //Default
            })
            const newUser = new User({
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email,
                avatar,
                password: req.body.password
            });
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt)=>{
                bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash)=>{
                    //if(err)throw err;
                    newUser.password = hash;
                    newUser.save()
                    .then(user=> res.json(user))
                    .catch(err=> console.log(err));
                })
            })
        }
    })
});
module.exports = router;
```

Finally my User Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
//Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    avatar:{
        type: String,

    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
});
module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

here is the error message from postman too

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:5000/api/users/register?name=RUGUMBIRA&email=rugumbirajordybastien@gmail.com&password=123456.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

Please help, what am i doing wrong

Comment: Are you sure you're sending all the required attributes (name, email, password) ?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message on the server, it appears you're using the Validator module as a validation middleware and the password field is required. But it also appears you're passing the registration details as a query while trying to access them in the req.body object. If this is the case, Validator sees req.body as empty and then throws the error.

Rather than pass the name, email, and password in the query, write them into the body of the Postman request. Click on the body tab on the Postman app and write in the registration details.